# Symfony Process - how to kill it?

Tags: php, symfony, process

I am launching some scripts via `Process` component. Sometimes those scripts fail and run forever, so I want them to be dead as soon as timeout expires.

I set the timeout via `Process::setTimeout()`. When the timeout is exceeded, `Process` object sends SIGKILL to the process. But because `proc_open()` executes a process in the shell, the signal kills only that shell wrapper, doesn't it?

Are there any legit ways to kill the child process using Process object? What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like you can prefix your command with `exec` to get rid of sh wrapper, see - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5759

Comment: @OlesSavluk it helped, thank you!